# How to implement fast search on Azure Blob?

Tags: c#, azure

I am done with writing the code to upload files (text files) to azure blob storage. Now I want to provide search based on text files content. For ex. If I search for "Hello" then the name of files that contains "Hello" words should appear in search result. Here my code to search

```
class BlobSearch
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string searchText = "Hello"; 
        CloudStorageAccount account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(azureConString);
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("MyBlobContainer");

        blobContainer.FetchAttributes();

        var blobItemList = blobContainer.ListBlobs();

        foreach (var item in blobItemList)
        {
            string line = string.Empty;
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(item.Uri.ToString());

            if(blockBlob.Name.Contains(".txt"))
            {
                int lineno = 1;

                using (var stream = blockBlob.OpenRead())
                {
                    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                    {
                        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                        {
                            if (line.IndexOf(searchText) != -1)
                            {                                    
                                Console.WriteLine("Line : " + lineno  +" => "+ blockBlob.Name);
                            }
                            lineno++;
                        }
                    }
                }                   
            }                
        }
        Console.WriteLine("SEARCH COMPLETE");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Above code is working but it is too slow. Is there any way to do it faster or Can improve above code.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: Hi, I am done with uploading and searching the blob item in blob container. But i looking for APIs that provide content based search  or any that solve this problem. Is it possible ?

Comment: searching through a blob is going to be slower than searching through a string. You're going to have to live with it.

Answer (score 0):

Blob Storage is not great for this kind of work, as file reads over HTTP are not very fast or random access. What you need is a search indexer like Lucene.

This Lucene.Net library looks like it could be what you're after:

https://azuredirectory.codeplex.com/